# Change material blend mode on all materials in scene

Tags: python, materials

I want to change the blend mode of all the materials in my scene at once and the only way that I think this would be possible is Python script but I simply have no idea how as I've never written a single line of python before...

```
import bpy

bpy.context.object.active_material.blend_method = 'OPAQUE'
```

This is what I currently have. How do I make it refer to all materials in the scene and not just the active one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import bpy
mats = bpy.data.materials

for mat in mats:
    mat.blend_method = 'OPAQUE'
```

[Link to the relevant class in the docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Material.html#bpy.types.Material.blend_method)